# Invalid authorization code" error when trying to get PayPal access token

Tags: paypal, oauth-2.0, paypal-sandbox, future

We are now adding PayPal future to our iOS application.
We are testing it with the sanbox of course but I keep getting "Invalid authorization code" error when I am trying to get an access toekn from OAuth2AuthorizationCode which we got from PayPal mSDK.

This is our request:

```
"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice",
"method":"post",
"headers":{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Authorization":"Basic QWFNdTNQYXBfcnNhSFFQTXl...."},
"body":"&grant_type=authorization_code&response_type=token&code=QzEwMS4z....."
```

And this is the response / error that we are getting:

```
{"status":400,"execution_time":397,"body":{"error_description":"Invalid authorization code","error":"access_denied","correlation_id":"XXXX",
"information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#errors"}}
```

Thanks